# Windows 7 - all files owned by login now "Access Denied"

Tags: windows-7, ntfs, file-permissions

On a laptop (running Win7 Pro) i have returned after a week away to find that every single file under my own profile (Edit - see below) is inaccessible to me. They are all there, but i have no permissions to do anything other than list the files in the folders. The only thing I'm aware of is that the network admin had to borrow my laptop briefly, but logged in as his own account (he is now on holiday), and some Windows updates were installed automatically when he shut it down (he has a roaming profile with Windows 8 which might be a factor). I am local admin on this device. I cannot view the permissions or file ownership on any file in my profile.

A few things that have been tried:

1) a different local admin account cannot access the files in any way.

2) a domain admin account cannot touch them.

3) changing my account to domain admin had no effect.

4) using TakeOwn in an elevated command prompt had no effect.

5) using psexec to run cmd as System and then trying TakeOwn to take ownership had no effect.

Every single one of those gives Access Denied. The files cannot be copied anywhere as a result.

A System Restore made no difference, nor did Safe Mode (although i haven't tried every permutation of user and Safe Mode yet).

The drive is encrypted with Safend Data Protection so a Linux bootcd is trickier, although that's probably the next thing to try.

Any ideas on how i can get my profile functional again? Or at least retrieve the files? I can't even open Event Viewer from this profile as it uses a settings file in the profile.

Edited: On further investigation, it appears that the locked files are not just those within my former profile directory - it appears that every file where my login was the owner is now inaccessible and the owner cannot be reassigned.

Edited 2: The problem now appears to be caused by the file encryption software - if i get a one-time-access key, i can access all the files. Unfortunately this is only usable after logging in, during which lots of files cannot be read. So I'm now trying to work out how to revert what was done.

Comment: As a local admin, you can always _take ownership_ of the whole tree. Do that, save that change, close the properties windows, and then try anything else again. You always need to do that as first step.

Comment: Not the case - first thing i tried. With the 'replace owner on subcontainers and objects' box checked i just get Access Is Denied on the files. Without it checked, nothing happens.

Comment: If you cannot change ownership it means, ownership was changed by a domain user, and your local user ownership removed.  You will have to wait for a domain administrator to solve your problem.  Its possible the files are owned by the user, and ownership was not provided to the domain administrator user group, the result is you need to determin what was done to the file by talking to the person who changed the ownership on the files.

Comment: Couple quick thoughts just in case you've not already tried: **1.** run chkdsk and let it fix any errors in case there's an issue at this level. **2.** with the McAfee Endpoint Encryption, do a whole disk decryption and then use a Linux live CD to get the data out of the folders to a new location you can access once booted to Windows to copy over to your new profile, etc. Classic example why you should store your critical or sensitive data in a network location as well just in case the HD hoses up as there's never a guarantee the data will be easily recoverable.

Comment: I've now identified the encryption software as the culprit (and also the correct encryption software). However, the software is actively messing up new files as well. These aren't critical or sensitive files, but recreating them will be very time-consuming.